# Apply to each item in content a event

Tags: c#, wpf

My first question is how to assign each of the items within the content to a event.
Which means each of the items has its own individual event.

What I have is a `RadialMenu`. Within it are `RadialMenuItems`. The user should be able to add and remove them how he wants, but the events must have same Functions yet individual for each of those items. (`Click`, `MouseEnter`, `MouseLeave`)

Here is what I have so far:

```
var i = 0;

radialMenu.Items.Add(new RadialMenuItem
    {
        Name = "Item" + i,
        Content = new System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock { FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold, Foreground = textBrush, Text = text },
        ArrowBackground = arrowBackgroundBrush,
        EdgeBackground = edgeBrush,
        Background = backgroundBrush,
    });
i++; 

foreach (var item in radialMenu.Content)
{
    item.MouseEnter += new MouseEventHandler( (sender, args) => { } );
    item.MouseLeave += new MouseEventHandler( (sender, args) => { } );
    item.Click += new RoutedEventHandler( (sender, args) => { } );
}
```

My second question is, is this approach a bad idea for WPF? 
If yes, how can I do better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
radialMenu.Items.forEach(item => item.Click += (se, a) => /*...*/);
```

Comment: THX, thats exactly what i was searching for. "Bodys were missing"

radialMenu.Items.forEach(item => item.Click += (se, a) => { } );